# What is the deal with Deadpool and Iron Man?

Tags: comics, iron-man, marvel, deadpool

So I was just curious:

I am new to Deadpool. In looking to start a collection I have seen a LOT of Deadpool/Iron Man variant covers. Is it just cool for the artists to draw that kind of thing, or do Wade Wilson and Tony Stark have an elaborate past that I haven't gotten to yet?

Spoilers are okay (with me), I enjoy reading them, however I've no desire to have my mind blown with unexpected twists.

Comment: Like the Iron-Man #9 variant (origins of Tony Stark) with the Deadpool mask. Or the Deadpool #9 variant with the Grey Iron-Man suit.

Comment: @Chad it is more than 1. Merc With A mouth #10 has an Iron Man Variant, Team Up #894 has an Iron Man variant, Volume 3 #22 has an Iron Man variant. etc. etc.

Comment: @Chad Links to the covers won't help anyone answer my question. Mainly because I am asking what the story between Deadpool and Iron Man is. I get Deadpool and Wolverine (Weapon X project)... Not Deadpool and Iron Man though. Someone suggested this is relatively new, others that it is just Deadpool stealing the other hero's spotlight. Just wondering if there is (already) an in depth story, if one is developing between them, or if it is completely superficial.

Comment: I Suggest you make the question more clear.  Provide links to the covers you are talking about and explain why you think there is a link.  It is not clear that there is from what you have posted currently.  So explaining why you think there is a link will help us explain those incedents to you.

Comment: @Grohlier I suggest appreciating Chad's advice. The described link between the two characters appears to be based on narrow context. I would say that the question is based on a false premise. Deadpool is always a popular crossover character. Additionally he serves as the voice of an author within the pages of his work.

Comment: @GorchestopherH The reason there is a narrow context is based on the fact I have a narrow understanding of the question at hand. I would love to give you more context... IF I had any... You both seem to be focusing on the covers. I know he appears on a LOT of covers. However, Iron-Man-esque pictures appear on Deadpool covers as well. The point of the question is simply "Is there a substantial link between Deadpool and Tony Stark/Iron Man, is there a new story arc forming, or is it simply Deadpool being Deadpool?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not just Iron Man. Deadpool has a huge "cult" following (so to speak) and there have been months where several titles had Deadpool variants all at once (if I remember correctly, esp. when X-Men Origins: Wolverine hit the theaters).

So he's been on the covers of . . .

Thor http://tinyurl.com/lpvdhot

Avengers -  http://tinyurl.com/kfbd2y2

Guardians of the Galaxy - http://tinyurl.com/jwumo2v

Wolverine: Savage - http://tinyurl.com/k9gpuj9

Amazing Spider-Man - http://tinyurl.com/l9dbe4o

etc. etc. etc.

Not only is he popular, but he's also one of the only Marvel comic characters to break the 4th wall (http://tinyurl.com/m4dveko), so it fits his modus operandi (sp?) to photo bomb the covers of other characters and steal their spotlight, so to speak. He's the one who actually knows fans are out there watching them!

Hope that's helpful. It's not just an Iron Man thing.

Comment: Deadpool has long been a fan favorite due to his... quirkiness, and Iron Man is probably the most popular due to the movies. I agree with FoxMan as Marvel does like to throw Deadpool around. Perhaps they even share some writers, drawers, inkers, etc.

Comment: This is as right an answer as this question is going to get. I would mention Deadpool's comic awareness. Deadpool was created as a link between characters with a voice outside of the context of the pages. He's linked to everyone.

Comment: @GorchestopherH , ah, yes, I forgot about the phrase "comic awareness." Make mine Marvel!

Answer (score 2):

Iron Man #9 from this [link](http://forbiddenplanet.com/99538-iron-man-9-now-deadpool-greg-land-variant/)

Description (should be vague enough to not give too much away)
The Secret Origin Of Tony Stark.

Death's Head and Iron Man team-up to hunt down a genocidal criminal. Not the problem. A shipful of dead badoon. Not the problem. What Tony finds in the depths of that ship: the problem. Big problem.

The lead into the biggest Tony Stark story of the year.

I don't recall Tony and Wade having a lot in common. I think this cross over is new

Comment: That isn't the only one though. Deadpool 7 (Marvel Now Reset) also shows Tony and Deadpool. Even reading them I can't figure out what their back-story is.

Comment: Yes, the Secret Origin of Tony Stark appears to be a long story arc